# xaml page doesn't wait for HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous

In my Windows Phone 7 application I'm getting data from web service.

So on start of my application I check is my data is setted in Local Storage and if it's not (first run) I have made request by `HttpWebRequest` and wait for response.

```
SetupAppData(); //chack in local storage
if (CheckNetworkConnection(false))
    if (appData == null)
        GetAppData();
...

    public void GetAppData()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("some url");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(RequestData_Completed, request);
    }
...
```

In `RequestData_Completed` I set request data and invoke `request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseData_Completed, request);`
Then when my response come back to the application I change it to my object and use in application.

But my problem is that I use this data in my xaml view before response come back. And I don't know how to make my view to wait for response.

I have tried to create some `bool` value `isDataSetted`, set it on true when my response come back and check its value in while loop but it block app and response never was handled.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just have `RequestData_Completed` fire an event after the data is processed, and have your UI respond when the event occurs.